# How to pass DB object in multi router setting in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, express, knex.js

I would like to make multiple router settings like the example in ExpressJS Doc.
I have index.js , api1 , api2 like below.
How can I pass the db object from index.js to api1 and api2?

I try with
`app.use('/api/v1', require('./controllers/api_v1')(db));`

but it shows errors:`Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`

index.js:

```
var express = require('../..');
const knex = require('knex');
const config = require('./config');

var app = module.exports = express();
const db = knex(config.db);

app.use('/api/v1', require('./controllers/api_v1'));
app.use('/api/v2', require('./controllers/api_v2'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from root route.')
});

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Express started on port 3000');
}
```

api_v1.js

```
var express = require('../../..');

var apiv1 = express.Router();

apiv1.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from APIv1 root route.');
});

apiv1.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.send('List of APIv1 users.');
});

module.exports = apiv1;
```

api_v2.js

```
var express = require('../../..');

var apiv2 = express.Router();

apiv2.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from APIv2 root route.');
});

apiv2.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.send('List of APIv2 users.');
});

module.exports = apiv2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export the db object from a database.js file and require it in the index.js file as well as every other file where you need database access. Or, an easier but uglier method, would be to make the variable global via `global.db = db`. You could then use `db` everywhere in your Node.JS application.

Comment: Thanks. It works but I have a question. Is there any performance issue if I import the DB object for each router? I may have 10 routers in my application.

Comment: It will not hurt your performance in any reasonable way. (Provided, that you only create one instance of the db object and not a new one for every router)